# i18next force detect language again

Tags: i18next, i18next-browser-languagedetector

I'm using the [browser language detector](https://github.com/i18next/i18next-browser-languageDetector) for [i18next](https://www.i18next.com/).

I'm using the default precedence, which is

```
['querystring', 'cookie', 'localStorage', 'navigator', 'htmlTag', 'path', 'subdomain']
```

I want to be able to set `localStorage.i18nextLng` dynamically, and have i18next update the language, but still respect the detection precedence.

Is there a way to tell i18next to run the language detector again? Or is there another way to accomplish this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can change the local storage value and then trigger [i18next.changeLanguage()](https://www.i18next.com/overview/api#changelanguage) to change on runtime.